# How to redirect to new URL after successful login to website?

Tags: xcode, swift, url, uiwebview, swift2

I am very new to Xcode and am looking to make an app using `UIWebView` that will bring me to specific URL that has login page and after a successful login I want it to redirect to a specific URL. This is a website for my company and I am making this app to ease when I am logging into our website. I have successfully made a `UIWebView` that brings me to the login page but unsure how I can detect a login to redirect next URL.

Comment: *"after a successful login I want it to…"*: How does your server inform the client whether login is successful?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using `UIWebView` for new code at this point.  Instead use `WKWebView`.

You must add a WKWebView to your view hierarchy programmatically.  To do so, add something like this:

```
var webView:WKWebView?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let webView = self.webView
    {
        view.insertSubview(webView, belowSubview: goButton)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -44)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let offset = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: goButton, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([height, width, offset])
```

Once that's done, you can use it by implementing `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation")

    if ( self.webView!.URL?.absoluteString == "https://myserver.com/successurl" )
    {
        print("SUCCESS")
        self.webView!.stopLoading()
        // do something here, like remove this from the nav controller
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("didCommitNavigation - content arriving?")
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    print("didFailNavigation")
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("didStartProvisionalNavigation \(navigation)")
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("didFinishNavigation")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
                               completionHandler: { (html: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) in
                                //print(html)
    })
}
```

You have a lot of control over the flow here, as you can see from all the protocol methods in the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` has a delegate you can set to a object that implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.  You can implement:

```
 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

In it.  So, a simple way to do it is to implement in the VC that hosts the web view.  Add:

```
, UIWebViewDelegate
```

to your class declaration.

You need to set the webView's delegate property to the view controller.

Then add this function:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
     // You can look at request and navigation type and decide to return 
     // false and redirect the webview yourself.
     // If the load is ok, return true.
}
```

If you need more control than this, you might want to look into the WebKit version of this (`WKWebView`), which is the preferred web view for new applications and has many more features for controlling it.